# Ошибка Nuitka: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '2.0.6' on Python '3.11' commercial grade 'not installed'

Tags: python, nuitka

ввожу
nuitka --follow-imports grace.py
после чего пишет Nuitka: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '2.0.6' on Python '3.11' commercial grade 'not installed'.
PASS 1: 94.7%|███████████████████████▋ | 71/75, telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist
и ничего не происходит

Comment: До этого делал такую же команду и оно работало, сейчас по какой то причине нет